# Class with underlying streamreader. Do I need to implement IDisposable?

Tags: vb.net, idisposable

In Visual Basic, I have code like this

```
Public Class MyReader

    Private _StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader

    Public Sub New(ByRef File As String)
        Me._StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(File)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Should I implement IDisposable with this class?  If a MyReader object goes out of scope, will .Dispose() automatically be called on the underlying StreamReader?

Comment: It will... eventually.  If it was me, I'd be implementing IDisposable so that consumers can dispose of your object (and your impl can dispose of the StreamReader)

Comment: I don't understand the point of this class. You are providing a wrapper (in name only) around framework functionality. Are you not showing how you are extending this class?

Comment: @Karl: I did not include the code extending the class. I wanted to provide the most succinct code possible for this discussion.

Comment: It will be garbage collected eventually after it goes out of scope.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: you can't count on garbage collection to call `Dispose` in all cases, and in any event, garbage collection can take minutes to get around to this member.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I never said GC would call Dispose; I only said that it would be garbage-collected eventually.  GC != Dispose

Comment: @DouglasBarbin: in the context of a question about `Dispose`, your comment suggests that GC would dispose.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to suggest any such thing.  GC will call the objects finalizer, which SHOULD then Dispose (but that doesn't necessarily mean that it will).

Comment: Even if the StreamReader would be eventually collected, I would implement IDisposable and dispose of it as fast as possible for one simple reason : When you debug, if you want to change the file the handle should be closed, and it will get closed when you dispose of it, so the faster you Dispose, the less troubles.

Comment: @Skyp Good point.  The garbage collector will NOT release the handle on the file, so he should either close the streamreader (and stream) explicitly to release the file, or Dispose of them (this releases any resources they might be using) or his entire class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research and hints from a few answers/comments here, I'm going to answer my own question.

The underlying StreamReader has unmanaged resources so we want to make sure it gets disposed of properly.

**Will the Underlying StreamReader Be Disposed of Automatically?**
Yes.  Any MyReader object is a managed resource which has an underlying StreamReader with unmanaged resources.  When MyReader goes out of scope, it will not sit and take up memory, but rather, *eventually* be picked up by the garbage collector.  The garbage collector will call Finalize() on the underlying StreamReader, which in turn calls its Dispose() method, releasing the StreamReaders unmanaged resources.

So, we don't *need* to implement IDisposable.

**Should We Implement IDisposable Anyway?**
Yes.  We can make the class better by implementing IDisposable and turning that *eventually* in the previous answer into an *immediately* (or at least an *as soon as possible*).  To get these benefits, we also must instantiate MyReader in a Using statement or call Dispose() on the MyReader when we are done with it.

After implementing IDisposable, the best way to use MyReader is

```
Using MR As New MyReader("Myfile.txt")
    'Do stuff
End Using
```

or

```
Dim MR As New MyReader("Myfile.txt")
    'Do stuff
MR.Dispose()
```

Feel free to note any errors I have made in the above answer.  I'm also interested in what bad things (if any) can happen if we do not dispose of MyReader and its underlying StreamReader manually and allow the garbage collector to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If your class holds objects which implement `IDisposable`, then your class needs to implement `IDisposable`. It's about that simple. There is no magic to cause `Dispose` to be called for all `IDisposable` members of your class.

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to Dispose without you explicitly calling .Dispose (or having the garbage collector .Collect eventually), then you need to wrap it in a Using like so:

```
Public Class MyReader

    Private _StreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader

    Public Sub New(ByRef File As String)
        Using _StreamReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(File)
            ' Do stuff here
        End Using
        ' At this point, _StreamReader is disposed of
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This severely limits the usage of the class, as once the constructor is done the reader might not be available as it might have been garbage collected.

Comment: This is fine, however, I need to hang on to the StreamReader after construction and not dispose of it immediately.  I have additional subroutines such as 'Public Sub ReadRecord' which need access to this StreamReader later.

Comment: Then you will either need to explicitly dispose of the StreamReader or make the class implement IDisposable if you want it disposed of once it goes out of scope.

Comment: @KarlAnderson Correct.  He would have to do whatever he is doing with _StreamReader in the constructor.  Since he gave us almost no code or idea of what he is trying to do, it's difficult to say what the usage of the class will be.  Thanks for the downvote, though.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin - I agree with the notion that it is almost impossible to figure out what the poster wants to do with this code. I have deleted my answer and will remove my downvote, I apologize.